# cloudera-manager-agent.rpm: does not update installed package error

Tags: centos, cloudera, yum, cloudera-manager

I was installing CM and CDH on CentOS6.9, some errors happended on one of the hosts.

So I want to reinstall cloudera-manager-agent, but failed.

Then I used rpm to reinstall(I had download the rpms), here is the result:

```
[root@xxx yum.repos.d]# rpm -e cloudera-manager*
error: package cloudera-manager-agent-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
error: package cloudera-manager-daemons-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
error: package cloudera-manager.repo is not installed
error: package cloudera-manager-server-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
error: package cloudera-manager-server-db-2-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
[root@vm8034 yum.repos.d]# rpm -U cloudera-manager*
error: cloudera-manager.repo: not an rpm package (or package manifest):
[root@vm8034 yum.repos.d]# rpm -U cloudera-manager*.rpm
package cloudera-manager-daemons-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64 is already installed
package cloudera-manager-server-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64 is already installed
package cloudera-manager-server-db-2-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64 is already installed
package cloudera-manager-agent-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64 is already installed
[root@xxx yum.repos.d]# rpm -q cloudera-manager*
package cloudera-manager-agent-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
package cloudera-manager-daemons-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
package cloudera-manager.repo is not installed
package cloudera-manager-server-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
package cloudera-manager-server-db-2-5.12.0-1.cm5120.p0.120.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

Comment: I solved this problem by  ```rpm -qa | grep cloudera``` and remove those packets by  ```rpm -e --noscripts xxx```.

Answer (score 0):

Try using yum instead of rpm and see if that works:

```
yum update cloudera-manager*
```

UPDATE:

Try a `yum update`. This will search for the available updates of your system and display a list with them. You can check if cloudera is in the list or not.

Then check the official website and see if there is any new version for download:
https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/manager/5-12-0.html

If there is try downloading the package, save it on your server and manually install it:

```
rpm -Uhv package-version-.rpm
```

Also you should check the content of `/etc/yum.conf` for an **exclude =** option. Usually that's used to exclude certain packages from update. If you find cloudera there, then that's why it will never update that package.

Comment: Thank you for answering me.But I tried this ,it doesn't work. Here is the result:                      
    ```No Packages marked for Update```

Comment: I solved this error by  ```rpm -qa | grep cloudera``` and remove those packets by  ```rpm -e --noscripts xxx```.  Thanks again.